# How can I solve these congruences?

Tags: number-theory, congruences

[image]

I have no idea, how to solve these congruences if you can help me please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could check the set $\{0,1,...,10\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice $2$ is a primitive root modulo $11$.  In other words, any number between $1$ and $10$ is congruent modulo $11$  to a unique power $2^k$ for $1 \leq k \leq 10$.  Notice $10 \equiv -1$, so on your first congruence you're really trying to solve $x^5 \equiv -1 \pmod {11}$.  Let's suppose $2^k$ is a solution for $x$ (so to find $x$, you'll have to solve for $k$), so $2^{5k} \equiv -1 \pmod{11}$.  Also $-1 \equiv 2^5$, so then $2^{5k} \equiv 2^{5}$.  But this is the same as saying that $$5k \equiv 5 \pmod{10}$$ Do you see why?  Also, note that now we have to work modulo $\varphi(11) = 10$ rather than mod $11$.  Anyway, it's easy to see that $k$ solves that congruence if and only if $k$ is odd.  So $k = 1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ are all the solutions to the congruence $5k \equiv 5 \pmod {10}$, so $$x = 2, 2^3, 2^5, 2^7, 2^9$$ will be all the solutions to the congruence $10x^5 \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$.

For the other problem, find a number $g$ such that $5g \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ (for example, $g = 9$).  Then the congruence $5x^5 \equiv 3 \pmod{11}$ is equivalent to the congruence $x^5 \equiv 27$, or $x^5 \equiv 5 $.  Apply the same type of argument as the first question.  Ask me if there's anything you don't understand about what I said.

Comment: thank you very much for your help and how can i find out what are the primitive roots of modulo 9? I can't answer this question...

Comment: and can you maybe to show the long version of the solution of the first problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: For your first question, there is no known formula for finding primitive roots.  You'll just have to test all the numbers $1, 2, ... , 8$ which aren't divisible by $3$ to see which ones generate the group of units modulo $9$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the long version?"  I gave you a pretty detailed explanation.  What part don't you understand?